# c-file cannot be execute in ssh

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, ssh

I work on vsc with remote-ssh. On local side the code works fine, but in ssh I can only compile the code (`gcc program.c -o program -std=c11`) but when I run it with `.\program`

I get the error message: bash: .program: command not found

What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `./program`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `./program`. In Bash, and Unix systems generally, the character to separate file system components is the forward slash, “/”. The backward slash, “\” is used to “escape” characters normal purposes and treat the character literally. So `\p` says to treat “p” as an ordinary “p”, which it already is. So `.\program` is equivalent to `.program`, which requests the shell to execute a file named `.program`. Since there is no such file, it gives you an error message.

Comment: wow..., works now, thanks.